# Android: How to change TextView in Activity from other class - best practice

Tags: android, textview

I got a TextView and a Button on my Activity Class.

When the Button is clicked I create an instance of another class, which does not extend Activity.

The other class does some calculation and then might want to change the textview.

I saw a lot of solutions but am looking for the best practice how to do this best (a set method in the main class? a handler? ... )

But I do not want to pass the content or stuff.

So it more or less looks like this:

```
public class MainClass extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
MyClass2 a = new MyClass2;
a.generateCodeOrSomething();
}
```

So class2 looks like this:

```
public class MyClass2{
public generateCodeOrSomething(){
double a=3.5;
}
```

Now I want to print 3.5 in the Textview but findViewById does not work and as I understand it is not a good idea either. 
When I create a method in MainClass  like

```
public valueChanged(double a){
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText(String.valueOf(a));
}
```

I cannot call it, or can I? Is that good practice or what would be?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why dont you just return the 3.5 from your dosomething method like valueChanged(a.generateCodeOrSomething); and directly update the TextView in your MainClass

Comment: hey. cause it is supposed to be part of a bigger project where I generate dummy data on another place or get them on another way and not really from the mainclass itself. so I want to hand the information to the mainclass on another way then a return value.

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback of some sort, e.g.

```
public interface CalculationFinishedInterface {
    public void onCalculationFinished(double result);
}

public class MyClass2 {

private CalculationFinishedInterface cfi;

public MyClass2(CalculationFinishedInterface cfi) {
    this.cfi = cfi;
}

public generateCodeOrSomething(){
    double a=3.5;
    if(this.cfi!=null) this.cfi.onCalculationFinished(a);
}

public class MainClass extends Activity implements CalculationFinishedInterface {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    MyClass2 a = new MyClass2(this);
    a.generateCodeOrSomething();
}

@Override
public void onCalculationFinished(double result) {
    textView.setText(result+"");
}
```

}